# ConcurrentHashMap where does get method lock?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp08223/) excellent article about the ConcurrentHashMap by Brian Goetz.  But when I was looking at the code of ConcurrentHashMap in more recent java version (1.8), I noticed a couple of differences

1. The next pointer in the MapEntry is not final, but rather volatile so it is possible to modify the list in the middle and not just beginning.

   ```
   static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
       final int hash;
       final K key;
       volatile V val;
       volatile Node<K,V> next;
   ```
2. Also I don't see where exactly the get method is obtaining the lock when it fails to lookup the key in the initial iteration

   ```
   public V get(Object key) {
   Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
   int h = spread(key.hashCode());
   if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
       (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {
       if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
           if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))
               return e.val;
       }
       else if (eh < 0)
           return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
       while ((e = e.next) != null) {
           if (e.hash == h &&
               ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))
               return e.val;
       }
   }
   return null;
   ```

   }

Can someone please explain how and where is the lock obtained in the get method, if at all?

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): 'retrieval operations do not entail locking'.

Comment: Thanks. But in the earlier version (1.5), there was a lock obtained during read when initial attempt to get value without lock returned null. Is that not the case with the recent versions and why?